# Compilation error for OnCheckedChanged event of checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I have checkboxes in my aspx page and oncheckedchanged event handler in the code behind.
My aspx page is as below

```
<div align="center">
    <table width="500px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset id="fs1" runat="server">
                    <legend>Type </legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CBNPatient" runat="server" Text="New Patient" OnCheckedChanged="CBNPatient_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CBNPhPatient" runat="server" Text="New Patient By Phone" OnCheckedChanged="CBNPhPatient_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <fieldset id="fsAdd" runat="server" visible="false">
                                    <table>
```

In the code behind,checkbox event handler is as below:

```
 protected void CBNPatient_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e  )
        {
            if (CBNPatient.Checked == true)
            {

                HtmlGenericControl fieldset = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("fsAdd");
                fieldset.Visible = true;
                PatAdd = true;               

            }
            else
            {
                HtmlGenericControl fieldset = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("fsAdd");
                fieldset.Visible = false;
                PatAdd = false;
            }

        }

        protected void CBNPhPatient_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CBNPhPatient.Checked == true)
            {

                HtmlGenericControl fieldset = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("fsAdd");
                fieldset.Visible = true;
                PhPatAdd = true;
            }
            else
            {
                HtmlGenericControl fieldset = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("fsAdd");
                fieldset.Visible = false;
                PhPatAdd = false;
            }
        }
```

I am getting a compilation error as below:

'ASP.framepages_registration_raddock_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'CBNPatient_CheckedChanged' and no extension method 'CBNPatient_CheckedChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.framepages_registration_raddock_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Check boxes are inside a fieldset.Does that cause any issue?

Please help me on this.
Thanks,
Soumya

Comment: Hello Soumya have you add reference on System.Web

Comment: @Soumya, could you post your page directives section?

Comment: Did you add those handlers recently?  It's possible your markup was changed but the code-behind did not rebuild for some reason.  Rebuild (and redeploy if necessary) the whole project.

Comment: I have System.web in my reference...

Comment: Please find  my page directive  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="raddock.aspx.cs" Inherits="UnicareSystemWeb.FramePages.Registration.raddock" %> In the code behind I am using                                  namespace UnicareSystemWeb.FramePages.Registration
{
    public partial class raddock : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

Comment: this is awkward. Try the following: (1) at your ASPX, go to the markup view, find one of those checkbox and remove the `OnCheckedChanged` attribute. (2) Switch to design view (3) Find the checkbox that you removed the delegate and double-click it. Let's see what method is created at codebehind

Comment: I was having some warnings and messages after building the solution.I have ignored them intially.Now after correcting all those,I am not getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Look, **this is not a complete answer** yet, but there are a few things that you should take care:

1. When you have boolean variables in a conditional statement (`if`), you don't have to compare them with `true` or `false`. Simply test them, like `if(CBNPatient.Checked)`
2. Look at your code, you are doing the same logic, just changing the bool value *according* to the selection of the checkbox. Both methods could be *much* simplified to this:

   ```
       HtmlGenericControl fieldset = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("fsAdd");
       fieldset.Visible = CBNPatient.Checked;
       PatAdd = CBNPatient.Checked;
   ```